# Prove that log Gamma is real analytic

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, special-functions

I came across a problem where I need to show that
$$
\Gamma'(1)-\frac{\Gamma'(y)}{\Gamma(y)} = \int_0^1\frac{(1-t)^{y-1}-1}{t}dt
$$
for all $y>0$.

I proved the case for $y>1$, where the integrated function is bounded, by finding a power series of the Beta function. Now I'm considering to show that both sides are analytic on $(0, \infty)$ so that the proof can be completed.

My thoughts are that,

- by replacing $(1-t)^{y-1}$ with its binomial series I can show the right hand side is analytic on $(0,\infty)$
- for the left hand side, I proved a result in previous problems that $\log \Gamma(y)$ is a smooth function and
  $$
  \frac{d^k}{dy^k}\log\Gamma(y) = (-1)^k (k-1)!\sum_{n=0}^\infty(y+n)^{-k}, k>1
  $$
  Note that $\frac{\Gamma'(y)}{\Gamma(y)} = \frac{d}{dy}\log\Gamma(y)$.

Did I miss some simple ideas to show that $\log\Gamma$ is indeed real analytic? I haven't studied complex analysis yet but any method is welcome.

Comment: Have you considered using Taylor's formula? You do know what real analytic means, don't you?

Comment: @skyking ahh... I missed the simplest way to check it. Thanks!

Comment: Would you still want somebody else to write the answer, or will you try yourself? Regardless I think the question is worthwhile...

Comment: @skyking yeah if someone would like to write the answer, it'll be great. I haven't got time to do it lately